# Proving the sequence $1/n$ doesn't converge in $(0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I'm trying to find an example of an incomplete space and prove explicitly, using the negation of the definition of convergence, that the sequence cannot converge.

Clearly in $\mathbb{R}$, the sequence $1/n \to 0$. So I take the induced metric on $(0,1)$, which doesn't contain this limit. I can say "in $\mathbb{R}$, the limit is unique, so restricting to a subset doesn't 'create' a new limit," but that doesn't seem sufficiently rigorous to me, so I'm trying to prove directly that for any candidate limit $M \in (0,1)$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$,  so that for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, I can find an $n \geq N$ such that $|p_n - M| \geq \epsilon$.

My first thought is to take $\epsilon = \frac{M}{2}$, but I don't know how to manipulate $|p_n - M|$.  To drop the absolute value, I'd want $\frac{1}{n} - M \geq 0$, so $\frac{1}{n} \geq M$, so $n \leq M$, but I need $n \geq N$. I'm including $0$ in my definition of natural numbers, so the $n = 0$ case would prevent me from just declaring that $n \geq N$ implies $n \geq M$.

Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: You are on the right track. In a Hausdorff space (or in a metric space, if you don't know topology), any sequence has at most one limit. So if $\frac1n$ has a limit in $(0,1)$, it has at least $2$ limits in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This makes far more sense to me. Thank you. I am curious how to prove it from the definition, though. Do you have any tips for that?

Comment: Here's a backwards way. Let $f(x) = { 1 \over x}$ and note that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. Suppose $x_n={1 \over n}$ converged to some $x$ then we would have $f(x_n) = n \to x$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $l \in (0,1)$. Show that there exists some $N$ so that for all $n >N$ you have
$$
\frac{1}{n} <\frac{l}{2} 
$$
But this contradictics the fact that $\frac{1}{n} \to l$ (WHY?).

Answer (score 0):

$(1).$ In a metric space $(X,d),$ a sequence $S= (x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $x\in X$ iff $$\forall r>0\,\exists n'\in\Bbb N\,(n>n'\implies d(x_n,x)<r\,).$$ Equivalently, iff $$\forall r>0\,\exists n'\in\Bbb N\,( d(x_n,x)\ge r\implies n\le n',).$$ Equivalently, iff $$(\bullet)\;\forall r>0\,(\{n: x_n\not\in B^X_d(x,r)\} \text { is finite }).$$ $(2).$ Let $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y,$ and let $r=d(x,y)/2.$

Then $\Bbb N=A\cup B$ where $A=\{n: x_n\not\in B^X_d(x,r)\}$ and $B=\{n:x_n\not\in B^X_d(y,r)\}$. Because by the $\triangle$ inequality we have $n\in \Bbb N\setminus A \implies x_n\in  B^X_d(x,r)\implies x_n\not\in B^X_d(y,r)\implies n\in B$. Now if $S$ converged to both $x$ and $y$ then $A$ and $B$ would both be finite by $(\bullet)$ (with $r=d(x,y)/2$), implying $\Bbb N=A\cup B$ is finite, which is absurd.

$(3)$. If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and if $S$ is a sequence in $Y$ and if $x\in Y$ then in $(\bullet)$ we have $x_n\not\in B_d(x,r)\iff x_n\not\in Y\cap B^X_d(x,r)= B^Y_d(x,r)$ for any $n.$ So a sequence $S$ in $Y$ converges in the space $Y$ to $x\in Y$ iff $S$ converges in the space $X$ to $x\in Y$.

Therefore, with $X=\Bbb R$ and $Y=(0,1)$ and $S=(1/n)_{n\in \Bbb N},$ if $S$ converged in the space $Y$ to $x\in Y,$ then $S$ would also converge in the space $X$ to $x\in Y$. But in $X$ we have $S$ converging to $0,$ so by the above paragraph (and by the uniqeness of limits in $X$) that would imply $0=x\in Y,$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence converges in a metric space to some $\ell$ if and only if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $\ell$ there is only a finite number of terms of the sequence outside of $U$.

But for any $\ell\in(0,1)$, you can choose, by Archimedan property of $\Bbb R$, some $n_0>2/\ell$, and then, $1/n$ is outside $(\ell/2,1)$ for $n\ge n_0$.